# Pycharm not recognizing django models, appconfig, etc

Tags: python, django, pycharm

I am using Pycharm 2021.1.1, It was all fine, suddenly when I try to write

```
from django.apps import AppConfig
```

It is showing `unsolved reference AppConfig`

```
from django.db import models
```

It is showing `Unsloved reference models`

But I have installed all necessary modules, like Django, DjangoRestFramework, and the actual virtualenv is activated.

Comment: check if you are still in the project virtual environment, it might be that it is got deactivated.

Comment: I reset the settings, then it worked fine, and venv was activated

Comment: are you still experiencing the problem, or you managed to fix it by resetting the project?

Comment: After resetting it worked, but is there any fix without resetting it?

Comment: Yes, it is possible. If you know where the initial virtual environment is, then you can instruct PyCharm to use it. This is done by going to File->Settings-> Project: ProjectName->PythonInterpreter and clicking on the wheel near Python Interpreter (on the right hand side). Here you can set up a new environment, or use the existing one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most probably because of cached data, if you find your project unsynchronized you can reset caches

`File` > `Invalidate Caches` , and mark `Clear file system cache` then `Invalidate and Restart`